# LdapConnection vs. PrincipalContext

Tags: c#, .net, ssl, active-directory, ldap

I have the following two implementations of authenticating users with LDAP and LDAPS and I was wondering which was better / more correct. For the record, both of these work on both SSL and non-SSL connections.

I'm also curious because when watching with Wireshark on the `Non-SSL PrincipalContext` version, I still see traffic on Port 636. Of the four combinations (`Non-SSL LdapConnection`, `SSL LdapConnection`, `Non-SSL PrincipalContext`, `SSL PrincipalContext`) it is the only one that has traffic on both Port 389 and 636 instead of just one or the other. What could be causing this?

**LDAP Connection Method:**

```
bool userAuthenticated = false;
var domainName = DomainName;

if (useSSL)
{
  domainName = domainName + ":636";
}

try
{
  using (var ldap = new LdapConnection(domainName))
  {
    var networkCredential = new NetworkCredential(username, password, domainName);
    ldap.SessionOptions.VerifyServerCertificate = new VerifyServerCertificateCallback((con, cer) => true);
    ldap.SessionOptions.SecureSocketLayer = useSSL;
    ldap.SessionOptions.ProtocolVersion = 3;
    ldap.AuthType = AuthType.Negotiate;
    ldap.Bind(networkCredential);
  }

  // If the bind succeeds, we have a valid user/pass.
  userAuthenticated = true;
}
catch (LdapException ldapEx)
{
  // Error Code 0x31 signifies invalid credentials, anything else will be caught outside.
  if (!ldapEx.ErrorCode.Equals(0x31))
  {
    throw;
  }
}

return userAuthenticated;
```

**PrincipalContext Method:**

```
bool userAuthenticated = false;
var domainName = DomainName;

if (useSSL)
{
  domainName = domainName + ":636";
  ContextOptions options = ContextOptions.SimpleBind | ContextOptions.SecureSocketLayer;

  using (PrincipalContext pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, domainName, null, options))
  {
    userAuthenticated = pc.ValidateCredentials(username, password, options);
  }
}
else
{
  using (PrincipalContext pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, domainName))
  {
    userAuthenticated = pc.ValidateCredentials(username, password);
  }
}

return userAuthenticated;
```

Comment: did you tried using @sindilevich answer ? any solution about it ?

Answer (score 6):

@DTI-Matt, in the examples above, you use `VerifyServerCertificate` callback that always returns `true`. This, essentially, defies the purpose of connecting to LDAP over SSL, as no real certificate check is performed.

While you could implement a real certificate check using `X509Chain` and/or `X509Certificate2` classes, it seems `PrincipalContext` handles the checks for you.

To summarize, both `LdapConnection` and `PrincipalContext` provide very similar functionality, in means of connecting to an LDAP server over plain or SSL connection. You have to supply `LdapConnection` much more hand-written code for it to work properly. On the other hand, `PrincipalContext` gives you the same functionality with less code to write by hand.

As a note, connections to port 636 (your default LDAP over SSL port), by non-SSL `PrincipalContext` may be explained by the fact this class tries to connect as secure as possible.

Answer (score 0):

This is what we ended up with that is working over SSL/Non-SSL.

```
public bool UserValid(string username, string password, bool useSSL)
{
    bool userAuthenticated = false;
    var domainName = DomainName;

    if (useSSL)
    {
        domainName = domainName + ":636";
    }

    try
    {
        using (var ldap = new LdapConnection(domainName))
        {
            var networkCredential = new NetworkCredential(username, password, DomainName); // Uses DomainName without the ":636" at all times, SSL or not.
            ldap.SessionOptions.VerifyServerCertificate += VerifyServerCertificate;
            ldap.SessionOptions.SecureSocketLayer = useSSL;
            ldap.AuthType = AuthType.Negotiate;
            ldap.Bind(networkCredential);
        }

        // If the bind succeeds, we have a valid user/pass.
        userAuthenticated = true;
    }
    catch (LdapException ldapEx)
    {
        // Error Code 0x31 signifies invalid credentials, so return userAuthenticated as false.
        if (!ldapEx.ErrorCode.Equals(0x31))
        {
            throw;
        }
    }

    return userAuthenticated;
}

private bool VerifyServerCertificate(LdapConnection connection, X509Certificate certificate)
{
    X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2(certificate);

    if (!cert.Verify())
    {
        // Could not validate potentially self-signed SSL certificate. Prompting user to install certificate themselves.
        X509Certificate2UI.DisplayCertificate(cert);

        // Try verifying again as the user may have allowed the certificate, and return the result.
        if (!cert.Verify())
        {
            throw new SecurityException("Could not verify server certificate. Make sure this certificate comes from a trusted Certificate Authority.");
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```