# ASP.NET Boilerplate Authentication via LDAP over SSL (LDAPS)

Tags: asp.net, active-directory, ldap, aspnetboilerplate

I am unable to confirm whether ASP.NET Boilerplate supports authentication using Active Directory's LDAP over SSL protocol. The [documentation](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Zero/User-Management#ldap-active-directory) states that LDAP protocol is supported but there is no mention of remote authentication mechanism using LDAPS or similar procedures.

I assume ASP.NET Boilerplate uses `System.DirectoryServices` namespace and its components under the hood to process the LDAP authentication and if so, would it be better to try and alter the Boilerplate's code to support LDAPS by doing something similar to [this](https://forums.asp.net/post/3978277.aspx) or should I separate the LDAPS implementation into custom class and avoid using Boilerplate's LDAP at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To be specific, Abp Zero Ldap uses `PrincipalContext` from `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` namespace

By default, it calls `principalContext.ValidateCredentials()` with `ContextOptions.Negotiate` to communicate with AD server

See https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/blob/14e41c9ce2d902b2661fca63f4074943e9036c5b/src/Abp.Zero.Ldap/Ldap/Authentication/LdapAuthenticationSource.cs#L98

You can try override `ValidateCredentials()` and pass `ContextOptiona.Negotiate | Context options.SecureSocketLayer` to `principalContext.ValidateCredentials()`

See more https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.contextoptions

Abp Zero Ldap module will still be recommended for you as it is well integrated with Abp Zero user login flow.

If you still want to use LdapConnection to validate with AD server, you can create your own ldap authentication source by extending from `LdapAuthenticationSource<TTenant, TUser>`

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I will try this route in hopes that modifying the mentioned Enum will be the only thing needed to switch to LDAPS but how certain can we be that's the only thing needing modification here?

Comment: Base on the documentation, it should be sufficient to use Context options for SSL connection. However, I did found a potential drawback for using PrincipalContext with self signed certificate. see https://stackoverflow.com/a/46901693/6856176